# Converting a multiline string to a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `string`:

```
Hoy
1
5
14
3
0
23
```

and I would like to turn it into a df.

I think it would be a good idea to turn to a `list(string)` and then `pd.Dataframe(list(string))`, however when I turn to a list return the following output:

```
['\n', 'H', 'o', 'y', '\n', '1', '\n', '5', '\n', '1', '4', '\n', '3', '\n', '0', '\n', '2', '3', '\n', '2', ',', '8', '3', '*', '\n']
```

Is there an alternative way to turn the initial string into a df such like this?:

```
     0
0   Hoy
1   1
2   5
3   14
4   3
5   0
6   23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv`, passing an IO buffer to it:

```
from io import StringIO

text = '''Hoy
1
5
14
3
0
23
'''   

pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), header=None)
     0
0  Hoy
1    1
2    5
3   14
4    3
5    0
6   23
```

Answer (score 3):

This should act as an argument for accepting @COLDSPEED's answer by observing how ugly this answer is.

```
txt = """Hoy
1
5
14
3
0
23"""

(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.to_numeric(x[1:], 'ignore'), name=x[0]))(
    txt.split('\n')
).to_frame()

   Hoy
0    1
1    5
2   14
3    3
4    0
5   23
```

Comment: Oh my... that is ugly! :D

Comment: For as ugly as it is this just works in 2020 because `StringIO` is no longer in `pd.compat`